# Showing only posts from the current user who is logged in?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, author

I'm using the following code to get ONLY posts with the post_type question and the current user who is logged in.

But if no use is logged in all the posts are displayed anyways.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
<?php global $current_user; ?>
<?php get_currentuserinfo(); ?>

<?php echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n"; ?>

<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'question',
    'post_author'  => $current_user->ID)
?>

<?php $custom_posts = new WP_Query(); ?>
<?php $custom_posts->query($args); ?>
<?php while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="block-2 border-top">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p><?php comments_number('0 Replies','1 Reply','% Replies'); ?>.</p>
        <p><?php display_votes(get_the_ID()); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_views(); ?></p>
    <span class="cat-links">
        <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', 'twentyten' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?>
    </span>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You could always conditionalise the query by checking if there's a user logged in, using `is_user_logged_in()` - [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in "is_user_logged_in Documentation").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is not valorize:    `$current_user->ID`  is `0`, so the query extracts all post, try to give it a non existent integer value

Try to substitute `$current_user->ID` with

```
($current_user->ID==0) : -1 ? $current_user->ID
```

It assign -1 to the author, if there is no user. So the query must return no results!